MS-Access-VBA issue trying to use OR when checking a text control for a value. Many values can show but I am only looking for ABC OR DEF
In my DB I need to determine the value of a text box on a form.  I am looking for specific results to continue with my code.  Here is what I am using now:
If Me.textcontrol.value = "ABC" OR "DEF" Then
    Me.anothercontrol.Enabled = True
Else
    ' Do something else
End If

This is failing to run and highlighted.  I tried to verify my OR statement had the correct syntax but could not find anything on the WEB.  I probably was not asking my question correctly.
Can you show me the proper way to use the OR statement in VBA?
I showed what I tried above.

This is not how OR works. It should be
If Me.textcontrol.value = "ABC" Or Me.textcontrol.value = "DEF" Then 
    Me.anothercontrol.Enabled = True 
Else
    ' Do something else 
End If

You could also do
Me.anothercontrol.Enabled = (Me.textcontrol.value = "ABC" Or Me.textcontrol.value = "DEF")


Thank you very much.  I just could not find this on the WEB and your quick response really helped me.

Then please mark as answered.
